# Python Unknown Error : Attribute Error with MongoDB database

Tags: python, database, mongodb, attributeerror

I have written a programme and I have tried to spilt my programme into multiple python files.
But it returns unknown Attribute Error which I did not know how to solve.

There are five parts for my codes.
The first part is called Database, which is my own database with some non-real data.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId

client = MongoClient(
    sample.com   # I hide my MongoDB account in here for security reason
)

db = client.Peter

user = db['User']
tx = db['Transaction']

db.User.drop()
db.Transaction.drop()

# Create
creative = [{'name': 'Peter', 'balance': 52642},
            {'name': 'Mary', 'balance': 57127},
            {'name': 'John', 'balance': 9000},
            {'name': 'Terry', 'balance': 29000},
            {'name': 'Tom', 'balance': 350000},
            {'name': 'Jason', 'balance': 21000},
            {'name': 'Ken', 'balance': 41400},
            {'name': 'Eva', 'balance': 21600}]

fake_record = [{'name': 'Peter', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue', 'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Mary', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Mary', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'John', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'John', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'John', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Terry', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Terry', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Terry', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Terry', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Tom', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Tom', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Tom', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Jason', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Jason', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Jason', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Ken', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue',
                   'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642},
               {'name': 'Eva', 'Transaction Type': 'Revenue', 'Transaction Category': 'Food', 'Transaction amount': 52642}]

db.User.insert_many(creative)
db.Transaction.insert_many(fake_record)
```

Part 2, the file below is my main programme.

```
from database import user, tx
import getpass
import inquirer
import time
from view import View
from store import Store


def main():
    print("Welcome to The Goldman Sachs Group Banking System !!!")
    p = getpass .getpass("Please enter your password : ")
    if (p == 'sunday'):
        view1 = View()
        view1.first_page()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Part 3, the codes below is my view programme, it contains all the screens (pages) that I have. The User of this programme will go through some of the pages below if they run this programme, and I will let them to select some of the options that I have given to them.

```
import inquirer
import time
from model import Player
from database import user, tx
from store import Store
import route


class View:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.player = Player()
        self.route = route.Route()
        self.store = Store()

    def first_page(self) -> None:
        # Question Section
        questions = [
            inquirer.List('page_1_result',
                          message="What do you want to do?",
                          choices=['Continue With Existing User',
                                   'Create New Player'],
                          ),
        ]
        answer = inquirer.prompt(questions)

        # Answer Section
        if answer['page_1_result'] == 'Continue With Existing User':
            self.current_user = self.player.enterOldPlayers()
        else:
            self.current_user = self.player.createNewPlayer()
        self.store.setUserName(self.current_user)
        # Routing
        self.route.goTo1()

    def second_page(self):
        # Question Section
        print(f"Hello {str(self.store.getUserName())},\n")
        questions = [
            inquirer.List('Please Choose Action',
                          message=f"What do you want to do?",
                          choices=['View all transaction',
                                   'Add Tansaction',
                                   'Back to previous page'],
                          ),
        ]
        answer1 = inquirer.prompt(questions)

        # Answer Section
        if answer1['Please Choose Action'] == 'Add Tansaction':
            self.route.goTo("Page 3 c1")
        elif answer1['Please Choose Action'] == 'View all transaction':
            self.route.goTo("Page 4")
        else:
            self.route.goTo("Page 1")

    def third_page(self):
        questions = [
            inquirer.List('Please Choose a type',
                          message="Please Choose a type",
                          choices=['Revenue',
                                   'Expense',
                                   'Back to previous page'],
                          ),
        ]
        self.transaction_type = answer1 = inquirer.prompt(questions)
        # Back to second page if they chosen this answer
        if answer1['Please Choose a type'] == 'Back to previous page':
            self.route.goTo("Page 2")
        self.route.goTo("Page 3__v2")

    def third_page_v2(self):
        questions = [
            inquirer.List('Please Choose a category',
                          message="Please Choose a category",
                          choices=['Food',
                                   'Transportation',
                                   'Rent',
                                   'Back to previous page'],
                          ),
        ]
        self.transaction_category = answer1 = inquirer.prompt(questions)
        if answer1['Please Choose a category'] == 'Back to previous page':
            self.route.goTo("Page 3")
        else:
            self.route.goTo("Page 3__v3")

    def third_page_v3(self):
        self.amount = float(
            input('Please enter a amount for the transaction:'))
        if self.amount != '':
            self.route.goTo("Page 3__v4")

    def third_page_v4(self):
        dummy1 = user.find_one({'name': self.store.getUserName()})
        questions = [
            inquirer.List('Confirm',
                          message="Did you confirmed all the data inputed is correct?",
                          choices=['Yes',
                                   'No, bring me back to the previous page', ]
                          ),
        ]
        answer1 = inquirer.prompt(questions)
        if answer1['Confirm'] == 'Yes':
            tx.insert_one(
                # transaction_type['Please Choose a type'] << This line was used to obtained the value
                {'name': dummy1['name'],
                    'Transaction Type': self.transaction_type['Please Choose a type'],
                    'Transaction Category': self.transaction_category['Please Choose a category'],
                    'Transaction Amount': self.amount}
            )
            # Update Balance
            balance = dummy1['balance']
            if self.transaction_type['Please Choose a type'] == 'Revenue':
                balance += self.amount
                user.update_one({'name': dummy1['name']}, {
                                "$set": {'balance': (balance)}})
            else:
                balance -= self.amount
                user.update_one({'name': dummy1['name']}, {
                                "$set": {'balance': (balance)}})
                # TODO: ADD A {} in that set of data
            print(
                f"You have entered a entry with ---> {self.transaction_type['Please Choose a type']}, {self.transaction_category['Please Choose a category']}, {self.amount}")

            print("The database has been updated, you will be sent to the first page")
            time.sleep(1.5)
            self.route.goTo("Page 1")
        else:
            self.route.goTo("Page 3__v2")

    def fourth_page(self):
        transactions = tx.find({'name': self.store.getUserName()})
        for transaction in transactions:
            print(transaction)
        print("All transaction has been shown from the database.")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        questions = [
            inquirer.List('back_or_not',
                          message="Do you want to go back to previous page?",
                          choices=['Yes',
                                   'No, bring me back to the first page', ]
                          ),
        ]
        answer1 = inquirer.prompt(questions)
        self.go_back_or_not = answer1
        if self.go_back_or_not['back_or_not'] == 'Yes':
            self.route.goTo("Page 2")
        else:
            self.route.goTo("Page 1")
```

Part 4, the codes below is my routes, it tells which page the User of this programme will go if they run this programme.

```
import view


class Route:

    def goTo(self, temp):
        if temp == "Page 2":
            self.user1 = view.View().current_user
            self.screen = view.View().second_page()
            return self.screen

        if temp == "Page 3":
            self.transaction_type = view.View().third_page()
            return self.transaction_type

        if temp == "Page 4":
            self.go_back_or_not = view.View().fourth_page()
            return self.go_back_or_not

        if temp == "Page 1":
            self.screen = view.View().first_page()
            return self.screen

        if temp == "Page 3__v2":
            self.transaction_category = view.View().third_page_v2()
            return self.transaction_category

        if temp == "Page 3__v3":
            self.screen = view.View().third_page_v3()
            return self.screen

        if temp == "Page 3__v4":
            self.screen = view.View().third_page_v4()
            return self.screen

    def goTo1(self):
        self.screen = view.View().second_page()
        return self.screen
```

Part 5, the codes below is called the model. It is to let the user decide whether to "use a old player" or "to create a new user" when they run this programme. Just a simple functions for this part.

```
from database import user, tx
import inquirer


class Player:
    def createNewPlayer(self):
        balance = 0
        name = str(input('Please enter a name for the new user:').capitalize())
        balance = float(
            input('Please enter a balance amount for the new User:'))
        new_user = {"name": name, "balance": balance}

        user.insert_one(new_user)
        return name

    def enterOldPlayers(self):
        users = user.find().sort("name")
        questions = [
            inquirer.List('user_selected',
                          message="Select a User",
                          choices=[user['name'] for user in users]
                          ),
        ]
        answer1 = inquirer.prompt(questions)
        return answer1['user_selected']
```

Part 6, the codes below called store. I want this part serves as a server. If the user input some variable. I want to save all the variables here. And whenever I wanted to call back those variable, I can call all the variables in this part.

For example, when the user run this programme, they need to select a player (i.e. an account). And then I want to save the account name that they have selected, and print their name out in every page of this programme.

```
class Store:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def setUserName(self, username):
        self.username = username

    def getUserName(self):
        return self.username
```

Here comes the problem: When I tried to run the App.py (The main part of my programme), it shows "AttributeError: 'Store' object has no attribute 'username'" in the file called "Store", which the the codes in part 6. That is, line 9, in "getUserNamereturn self.username".

I have a little bit idea of why this Error will happen. It is probably because I have clear the variable that I have stored when I run the code in part 3 of my code in the line "self.store = Store()".

Since I deliberately separate a very big file into multiple files, just like these example.
If I want to keep these six part of files that I have , what should I do to solve this problem?

I know that in Java Script, there is a system called "state management" can solve this problem. But I don't know how to solve it in Python.

Thank you very much!

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Looks like you're running getUserName before setting the value. I'd recommend either setting it in the constructor or making sure the Store has the value using hasattr() before getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good practice to set any class attributes in the `__init__` method of your class.

If you don't do this, and reference the attribute before it is set, you will get an `AttributeError`.

This code is a bit safer; if you try and get the username before it it set, it will return None, which is a big clue that you haven't set the username.

```
class Store:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.username = None

    def setUserName(self, username):
        self.username = username

    def getUserName(self):
        return self.username
```